# Python: Numpy combine arrays into 2x1 lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm hoping to combine two arrays

```
 A: ([1,2,5,8])
 B: ([4,6,7,9])
```

to

```
 C: ([[1,4],
      [2,6],
      [5,7],
      [8,9]])
```

I have tried insert, append and concatenate, they only lump all elements together without giving the dimension in C.

I'm new to Python, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `print(list(map(list, zip(A,B))))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`numpy.column_stack`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

> Stack 1-D arrays as columns into a 2-D array

```
np.column_stack((A, B))

array([[1, 4],
       [2, 6],
       [5, 7],
       [8, 9]])
```

Comment: How do you select 1 or 2 from the stacked array? Select individual element from the sublists?

Comment: To select from the first column, start indexing using `arr[:, 0]`, and for the second column, use `arr[:, 1]`

Comment: I tried that, but it will give me an entire column. I only need the individual element such as 1,2 or 4

Comment: Just read up on numpy indexing, if you wanted `1`, you would use the first row, first column, so `arr[0, 0]`

Answer (score 1):

According to your initial approach, you only need to use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip), which returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

```
import numpy

A = numpy.array([1,2,5,8])
B = numpy.array([4,6,7,9])

print(list(zip(A, B)))
```

It will print:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 6), (5, 7), (8, 9)]
```